# Seagate 3TB drive not showing up in Device Manager in Windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, device-manager

**Context**

My aunt gave me a 3TB Seagate external USB drive for Christmas. It takes a little jiggling (power cycle) to work on my Mac, where it shows up as a perfectly functional NTFS partition, but in Windows 7, it doesn't even show up in Device Manager. If it showed up there, and in `diskpart`, I'd have no trouble getting it to work as a removable drive in Windows. But alas, Device Manager doesn't show it.

The drive *did* show up once in Device Manager, with a yellow exclamation mark. When I connected the drive, Windows raised a system tray balloon error about the device failing to update the driver. I tried manually updating the driver, as well as uninstalling the driver and repeating from scratch, to no avail. Now the Seagate doesn't show up at all in Device Manager.

TL;DR. The Seagate white LED is on. The drive functions as an NTFS partition in Mac, but in Windows, it doesn't even show up in the Windows Device Manager.

**Troubleshooting**

- I tried rebooting. Didn't help.
- I tried showing hidden devices in Device Manager. Didn't help.
- I tried deleting all USB devices in Device Manager and then rebooting. Didn't help.
- I tried unplugging the Seagate drive completely. Didn't help, though it was necessary to work with my Mac.

Google searches don't yield good results; most USB drive problems are easily fixed with `diskpart` -> `select volume ABC` -> `assign letter=X`, so 95% of Google results are that.

However, one tutorial suggested malware may be hiding USB drives. I'm installing Avast and checking if this is the problem.

Also, a tutorial recommended using a Windows installation disc to repair Windows, which would fix any corrupted USB drivers. The Asus laptop didn't come with a Windows disc but fortunately I was able to find one.

**Specs**

- Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Desk 3TB (PN: `9ZQ2P6-500 3 TB`, though the Seagate website refuses to recognize the number in order to search for driver downloads)
- Windows 7 Home SP1 x64
- Asus A5SE laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yet another](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2010159) tutorial suggests disabling the **automatically turn off USB devices to save power** setting. Effecting this change, then replugging in the Seagate drive finally fixed it for me!

Comment: Great but strange... :)